# What exactly is saved when I save a NN?

Tags: neural-network, keras

After we trained a Neural Network, we can save it in order to be able to predict without re-training. So when we use `model.save('my_model.keras')` what exactly is being saved?

[tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load?hl=en#save_the_entire_model) says:

> Save a model's architecture, weights, and training configuration in a single model.keras zip archive.

What exactly does it mean "model's architecture, weights, and training configuration". Is it a set of matrices? Or is there a better way to visualize it?

For reference here is my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(X_train_scaled.shape[1],)))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(42, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))  # Linear activation for regression
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_absolute_error')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The saved data comprises:

- **Model's architecture**: so, which layers your model has (Masking, Dense, Dense, Dense), their definition (e.g. the input/output shapes, activations, `mask_value = 0` for the `Masking` layer, etc), and how they are connected (i.e. `Masking` --> `Dense` --> `Dense` --> `Dense`).
- **Weights**: the trainable parameter values of each layer (e.g. kernel and bias for Dense layers). These are the matrices that you were referring to in your question.
- **Training configuration**: optimizer, loss.

The goal is to save all data needed to restore the model later.